# NSLog shows values, but context doesn't save data

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm making the app using core-data. 
It's facebook app, so I saved the User information to core-data.
And I wanna add the profile picture to user information data.

```
    for (UserInfo *info in fetchedObjects) {
        if ([info.fbId isEqualToString:delegate.currentUserInfo.fbId]) {
            info.details.photos.image  = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
            info.details.photos.imageId = [result objectForKey:@"id"];
            info.details.photos.details = info.details;

            delegate.currentUserInfo = info;

            for (UserInfo *info in fetchedObjects) {
                NSLog(@"currentUserInfo : %@", info);
                NSLog(@"curretnUserDetails : %@", info.details);
                NSLog(@"currentUserPhoto : %@", info.details.photos);
            }

            if (![context save:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Like this, I add the data to the core-data (relationshop named photos) corresponding to FB user ID.

As a result, NSLog in the middle shows well photoInfo data, but when I restart my app, there is no photo data. 
I didn't solve this problem for a few days. Help me!

-edited

[image]

DataModel is organized like this picture. 
I'm using only one context, and I'm novice so I can't understand all of thankful comment.

-edited2

```
 if (!beExist) {
        UserInfo *userInfo = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"UserInfo" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        userInfo.name = [myInfoDic objectForKey:@"name"];
        userInfo.fbId = [myInfoDic objectForKey:@"id"];
        userInfo.type = @"user";
        UserDetails *userDetails = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"UserDetails" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        userDetails.gender = [myInfoDic objectForKey:@"gender"];
        userDetails.work = [[[[myInfoDic objectForKey:@"work"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"employer"] objectForKey:@"name"];
        NSArray *eduArray = [myInfoDic objectForKey:@"education"];
        userDetails.education = [[[eduArray objectAtIndex:eduArray.count-1] objectForKey:@"school"] objectForKey:@"name"];
        userDetails.birthday = [myInfoDic objectForKey:@"birthday"];
        userDetails.location = [[myInfoDic objectForKey:@"location"] objectForKey:@"name"];
        PhotoInfo *photoInfo = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"PhotoInfo" inManagedObjectContext:context];

        userDetails.info = userInfo;
        userInfo.details = userDetails;
        userInfo.details.photos = photoInfo;
        photoInfo.details = userDetails;

        delegate.currentUserInfo = userInfo;

        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
```

I saved User information like this.
I created context in AppDelegate. I made the project for Core data, so Xcode made that code.

I can see this log

```
2012-05-04 00:40:58.997 Feek[16423:fb03] currentUserPhoto : <PhotoInfo: 0x6d15d60> (entity: PhotoInfo; id: 0x6d18550 <x-coredata://2ED200FE-D799-4C66-A0AC-5BE1BC426439/PhotoInfo/p1> ; data: {
details = "0x8830ca0 <x-coredata://2ED200FE-D799-4C66-A0AC-5BE1BC426439/UserDetails/p1>";
image = <ffd8ffe0 00104a46 49460001 02000001 00010000 fffe0004 2a00ffe2 021c4943 435f5052 4f46494c 45000101 0000020c 6c63>;
imageId = 334168116641714;
})
```

I think that this is core data accept data, but it doesn't remain after killing my app.